# How to use multiple stripe-checkout components using vue-stripe?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create 2 options for subscriptions, one option is monthly, the other is yearly.
In the vue file I have these 2 vue-stripe components:

```
  <stripe-checkout
    ref="checkoutRefMonthly"
    mode="subscription"
    :pk="stripeKey"
    :sessionId="monthlySessionId"
  />
  <stripe-checkout
    ref="checkoutRefYearly"
    mode="subscription"
    :pk="stripeKey"
    :sessionId="yearlySessionId"
  />
```

A button that calls the submit function:

```
  <button @click="submit('monthly')">
    Choose monthly
  </button>
```

And a function that returns a vue-stripe function:

```
submit(type) {
  if (type === 'yearly') {
    return this.$refs.checkoutRefYearly.redirectToCheckout();
  }

  return this.$refs.checkoutRefMonthly.redirectToCheckout();
},
```

The problem is, that only a one component is working at the time, I thought that providing different ref values I could call accordingly a different function, one for montly subscriptions, the other, for yearly.

The error I get for the other component on submit:

```
IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId
```

I double checked the sessionId values for both components, they are different and set as needed, my guess is, the this.$refs.{name}.redirectToCheckout() ignores the name and calls the same function with the first loaded stripe-checkout parameters.

How could I have 2 different subscriptions components in the same view?

Comment: Doesn't directly answer your question, but maybe just use a single PricingTable component and embed that in the page instead, would probably solve the same use case with less code. https://stripe.com/docs/no-code/pricing-table

Comment: You're setting up Legacy Stripe Checkout, but using `redirectToCheckout`, which is a disused function for Stripe's new Checkout. These are not compatible. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration I would suggest pricing tables - suggested above - or Payment Links : https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links

Comment: @Lucky2501 Wow, payment links are amazing! So easy to setup! Big step forward for stripe.